# Date format in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

SlickGrid launches the calendar using a default US date format of mm/dd/yyyy. I store dates in my database in Australian format dd/mm/yyyy. how can I change the format of the calendar to take dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DatePicker of your choice by writing a new custom editor. The default date editor uses jQueryUI DatePicker. 
Personally (I'm in Australia too), I use the default with the following settings:

```
function DateFormatter(rowIndex, cell, value, columnDef, grid, dataProvider) {
  if (value == null || value === "") { return "-"; }
  return moment.utc(value).format('ddd, D MMM YYYY');
}
```

... using `moment.js` to format the date, and in the DateEditor ...

```
$input.datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'd/m/yy',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif"
});
```

Also you could just [localise](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)

Answer (score 0):

You can write formatter for row (i use **moment.js** too):

```
function dateTimeFormatter (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    var dateTime = Date.parse(value);
    var result = moment(dateTime);
    return result.format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss');
}
```

Comment: I use MomentJS as well for date formatter but your approach is not bulletproof and will possibly fail when Moment can't figure out which format for you're using, you can however simply provide it as second argument `moment(value, inputFormat).format(outputFormat);`

Answer (score 0):

First, add code to the slick.formatters.js file in your local library:
Add the custom date formatter in two spots:

```
$.extend(true, window, {
"Slick": {
  "Formatters": {
    "PercentComplete": PercentCompleteFormatter,
    "PercentCompleteBar": PercentCompleteBarFormatter,
    "YesNo": YesNoFormatter,
    "Checkmark": CheckmarkFormatter,
    "Checkbox": CheckboxFormatter,
    "Date": Dateformatter //<<  this one
  }
}
```

});

and on the end of the file:

```
function Dateformatter(row, cell, value, columndef, datacontext) {
        if (value === null) {
            return "";

        } else {
            var d = new Date(value);
            var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + m + "/" + d.getFullYear());
        }
       
 }
})(jQuery); //<< this line is already present
```

Now you can add the date formatter in your column definitions:

{
id: "lastLoginDate", name: "LastLoginDate", field: "lastLoginDate",  formatter: Slick.Formatters.Date
},